# dataexporter export empty rows containing link

Tags: excel, datatable, primefaces, hyperlink, data-export

In my dataTable, I have links to another page. Unfortunately, the export in Excel format produces empty rows. Without the links, the export works fine.

So what shall I do to have a link and export the table ?

```
    <h:form id="componentForm">

    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" >
        <p:outputLabel for="upper" value="Date max:"/>
        <p:calendar id="upper" value="#{futuresExpireView.upper}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/> 

        <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Charger" action="#{futuresExpireView.loadTable}" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:dataTable value="#{futuresExpireView.infos}" var="item" id="infos" >
        
        <p:column headerText="Libellé"  >
            <p:link outcome="security">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.security.label}" />
                <f:param name="securityId" value="#{item.security.securityId}" />
            </p:link>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

    <br/>

    <p:commandButton id="export" value="Export XLXS" ajax="false">
        <p:dataExporter type="xlsxstream" target="infos" fileName="futures" />
    </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

It works fine without the link :

```
        <p:column headerText="Libellé"  >
            <h:outputText value="#{item.security.label}" />
        </p:column>
```

Comment: PF version? Have you tried adding value tag at your link?

Comment: I user PF 8.0. As a workaround, I export manually my data.